# Bigcommerce Store Settings Not Applied Locally to Stencil Theme

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm developing a Bigcommerce Stencil-based theme and there are some store settings that are being ignored when serving it locally. For instance, if I turn off "Enable Image Zoom" in the store settings, it is still enabled locally. Or if I turn off "Show Tiny Thumbnails" the thumbnails still show. I hesitate to rip out that code from the theme files, but is that the only way to handle this stuff locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While transitioning from Blueprint to Stencil, some settings will still be visible in the control panel that do not affect Stencil.

The reason for this being that in Stencil, we've moved these settings into the theme itself so they can be controlled by a theme editor and saved on a per theme basis. Blueprint, however, relies on global store settings and doesn't retain store setting styling that might occur.

You'd want to make these changes within the [Stencil config file](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/themeeditor-configuration).